# SQLite BackupDatabase method is throwing exception after upgrading to version 1.0.111.0

Tags: c#, vb.net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am upgrading System.Data.SQLite from version 1.0.93.0 to 1.0.111.0

I am having a method which copies the SQLite database on disk to in memory. It is working fine with version 1.0.93.0 and here's the code in VB.Net

```
Dim sourceConn = CType(_connection, System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection)
Dim destConn = CType(destDBM._connection, System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection)

sourceConn.BackupDatabase(destConn, "main", "main", -1, Nothing, 0)
```

where path of destination SQLite is in memory by using **":memory:"** instead of path.

After upgrading to version 1.0.111.0, it throws the below exception

> code = Unknown (-1), message = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): unknown error
>   failed to initialize backup
>      at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.InitializeBackup(SQLiteConnection destCnn, String destName, String sourceName)
>      at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.BackupDatabase(SQLiteConnection destination, String destinationName, String sourceName, Int32 pages, SQLiteBackupCallback callback, Int32 retryMilliseconds)

Does anyone have any idea that how to get it solved?

Comment: Please review the change log, there is 5 years of changes from 1.0.93 to 1.0.111. There are a few marked "incompatible change". https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki

Answer (score 2):

I am able to find out the root cause of this issue myself. Actually, I was starting a transaction in destination database before backup. It was working fine in the older version but the behavior is changed in the latest version and exception is not meaningful at all.

To fix it, I have re-ordered the code which was initiating transaction as the next step after taking backup. It's working as expected now and insertions are way too fast in the latest version. Great work by SQLite team!

Comment: I just want to remark that the transactions of BOTH databases must be closed to complete the backup operation. Otherwise you'll get a "unknown error" by sqLite!